# Display list in table view by using google places api

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, google-places-api

I have three things in my table: Institute, Restaurant, Hospital. I want that by clicking on Restaurant, I should find the restaurant names near by 1km by using google places API. 
I have been using this....

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=33.833207,-117.918921&radius=800&types=restaurant|Cmeal_takeaway|Cmeal_delivery|Cbakery|Cfood&sensor=false&key=APIKEY"];
```

for specifying places type.....
How should I go ahead?? I don't find any question related this.. please help me....

Comment: Your link returns an XML. Parse it and use it.

Comment: Check also that you have enabled Places API in your google account.